# C#/Xamarin equivalent of class.getSimpleName()

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I'm manually porting an Android Studio project to Visual Studio / Xamarin. I have this Java code:

```
throw new IllegalStateException(MyClass.class.getSimpleName() + " is not initialized.");
```

and I'm trying to find the equivalent for `.getSimpleName()`.

I found a couple things on the web to try:

```
throw new IllegalStateException(MyClass.ShortClassName +" is not initialized.);
throw new IllegalStateException(nameOf(MyClass) +  " is not initialized.");
```

but neither of these compile.
Can you tell me what the equivalent is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can try with `typeof(myclass).Name`. Just for completeness, if you need the extended name with namespace, use:`typeof(myclass).FullName`

Comment: Thanks, that compiles.

Answer (score 1):

What are probably looking for is some information from the [`Type`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type(v=vs.110).aspx) class.  The [`Name`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.name(v=vs.110).aspx) property will give you the "simple" name of the class, where [`FullName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.fullname(v=vs.110).aspx) gives you a fully qualified name for the class.